# Folder /label highlighting in Mavericks 10.9

Tags: macos, finder-tag

I used the tags / label color highlighting feature in the past OS's extensively to order my folders. Now I've changed to 10.9 they seem to have all changed to a little dot, which is not as easy to see. Is there a way to get Mavericks to allow you to color the file / folder name as in previous versions of the OS?

---

Background

I tend to view my folders using the list view as below

[image: list view]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use an application called Folders Factory for that.

You can [download it from the Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/folders-factory/id442153412) and it only costs $2.99, so it will not break your budget, but it has some very fancy features you might like.

Comment: Thanks @buscar - Do you know if that allows you to change the add colour to the a folder name rather than colouring the folder itself - I tend to view my folders in list view so colouring the folders wouldnt work that well (also if they were files not folders i think id run into an issue)

Comment: Not easy, those are system level fonts and not recommended to change.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the free Extension "[XtraFinder](http://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/)". Since Version 0.19 there is a new Option in "Appearance" called "Leagacy Color Label Painting" which brings back the color background in the finder-listmode.